# I do not understand why these javascript variables are undefined in Visual Studio 2010 debugger

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-2010, debugging

I have a small code snippet that is giving me trouble and I cannot see the error:

```
function foo()
{
   var rowLabels = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H'];
   var colHeaders = ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '10', '11', '12'];

   for (i=0; i < rowLabels.length ; i++) {
      for (j=0; j < colHeaders.length; j++) {
         var id = rowLabels[i] + colHeaders[j]; 
         // e.g. A1, A2, A3...        
      }       
   }
}
```

When I place the breakpoint of the Visual Studio 2010 debugger on the line:

```
  var id = rowLabels[i] + colHeaders[j];
```

the debugger reports that **i** and **j** are *undefined*.

ADDENDUM:  VS2010 debugger also reports undefined when I do `for (var i = 0;...`

ADDENDUM2:  Firebug has no problem with the code. I think it's something screwy with VS2010.

Comment: Where is the `var` declaration for "i" and "j"?

Comment: I'm getting the same undefined error when using the var declaration.

Comment: I assume your variables aren't undefined at all. You just have a bad debugger. Just run it in Chrome with Developer Tools open. You can breakpoint it fine and see all your variables.

Comment: @DDS: sometimes VS does act very flaky indeed.  I like the Javascript Parser extension, though. Very useful utility. http://code.google.com/p/js-addin/   Anything like it available for Notepad++?